# Python count all boolean values in pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

Does anybody have an idea  how to count all boolean values(including the false one) in pivot table?

`passed_exam` is a column of boolean values.

This code performs the task only for true values which is great:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["student","semester"], values=["passed_exam"],aggfunc=np.sum)
```

But I also want a column that counts all boolean values.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Negate the table, do the same, add the two values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), last reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'student':['a'] * 4 + ['b'] * 6,
                   'semester':[1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                   'passed_exam':[True, False] * 5})

print (df)
  passed_exam  semester student
0        True         1       a
1       False         1       a
2        True         2       a
3       False         2       a
4        True         1       b
5       False         1       b
6        True         2       b
7       False         2       b
8        True         2       b
9       False         2       b

table = df.groupby(["student","semester","passed_exam"])
          .size()
          .unstack(fill_value=0)
          .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
          .reset_index()
print (table)
  student  semester  False  True
0       a         1      1     1
1       a         2      1     1
2       b         1      1     1
3       b         2      2     2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it possible not to repeat a and b? I mean to have a in the first row and then blank in the second row? and always getting a dataframe as a result

Comment: Sure, can you create new question with sample data, desired output and what you try? Thank you.

Comment: And use my sample, no problem, or you can change it as you need. Maybe help [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).